# Authorize.net AIM Module Subscriptions

Tags: authorize.net

Working with a very 'niche' merchant account provider that I've managed to add to Authorize.net. We need to accept subscription payments through our website, and require a module that supports recurring subscription payments using the Authorize.net AIM module. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Yeah, I use Paradox Lab's Authorize.net CIM extension- it's amazing, but I haven't seen any mention of AIM. What do you need AIM for, specifically? As a side note, looks like authorize.net is officially calling AIM "Payment Transactions" in their documentation : http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions